# Dojo TextArea Not Working

Tags: dojo

I'm following this guide using the declarative example: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Textarea.html#id2

But for some reason it's not working at all. It shows that it's working in the example on the Dojo site, but when I put it on my webpage it doesn't do what it's suppose to do, which is auto resize the text area to the content. The first example, programmatic, works fine.

Here you can see that on Plunker it's also not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/v5MngysRgo5509isCMa1?p=preview

I've inserted both example and as you can see, the programmatic way works but the declarative way isn't.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already found out you have to parse the page. This can be done either manually using the `dojo/parser` module or automatically by providing a `dojoConfig` object (or `data-dojo-config`) and using `parseOnLoad: true`.

You're using this last approach but there's one small (and important) detail. The `dojoConfig` must be loaded **before** the `dojo.js` script. I recommend reading [this Dojo tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/) which is all about configuring Dojo.  The second yellow notice/block already says that:

> Notice that dojoConfig is defined in a script block before dojo.js is
>   loaded. This is of paramount importance—if reversed, the configuration
>   properties will be ignored.

Another thing I noticed in your example is that you also need a Dojo theme for most widgets to work properly. You can do this by adding a theme like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css` and then you only need a parent with the `class="claro"` attribute. Usually it's done at the `<body>` tag.

I forked your Plunker code and updated it a bit. I'm not used to Plunker but I think this is the correct URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/O4A6pWnpXRGyVr4gzZ8x?p=preview

Comment: Can't believe it was THAT simple! Ahh that drove me nuts. Thank you also for the extra information. Wish I can upvote twice.

Comment: I am in a similar problem, need assistance